# Android LG K-210 bandwith info for Taiwan

Tags: bandwidth, mobile-phone

I have a Canadian LG K210 (LG Power) phone that was unlocked by the carrier Telus which I was able to use in Malaysia (for data and calling) and Thailand (calls only).  Here in Taiwan, neither seems to work.
Here is the phone:  [K210 Canada info](https://www.phonemore.com/specs/lg/x-power/k210/)

It says:

> GSM Mhz band  Quad-Band 850/900/1800/1900 Primary 2G network  GSM
>   850/900/1800/1900 Primary 3G network  UMTS 850/1700/2100 Primary 4G/5G
>   network   LTE Cat4 700/850/1700/1900/2600 (Bands 2,4,5,7,12,17) Primary
>   data network  GPRS, EDGE, UMTS, HSDPA, HSUPA, HSPA+, LTE

And this is what I found about the my carrier Fareast One's bandwith in Taiwan:

[Taiwan bandwith info](https://www.frequencycheck.com/carriers/taiwan-mobile-taiwan)

> Frequency Bands GSM Name  Interface 900 (E-GSM)   GSM 1800 (DCS)  GSM
>
> UMTS Name Interface B1 (2100) UMTS Supported UMTS Protocols
>   Name  Generation UMTS 3G HSPA+    3.5G (4G speed)
>
> LTE Name  Interface B3 (1800 +)   LTE B28 (700 APT)   LTE Supported LTE
>   Protocols Name    Generation LTE  4G

I am seeeing some overlap with the numbers but not sure what I should be looking for as there are three other carriers I could switch to listed here:  [other carriers in Taiwan](https://www.frequencycheck.com/carriers?commit=Search&q%5Bcountry_id_eq%5D=222&q%5Bfrequency_bands_id_eq%5D=&q%5Bname_cont%5D=&q%5Bs%5D=carrier_frequencies_count%20desc&utf8=%E2%9C%93)